# Ajax and sessions dosen't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I need to post something in ajax , and save it in sessions

This is the post code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".q").on('change', function postinput(){
    var q = $(this).val(); // this.value
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); // this.id
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'api/save?id='+id+'&q='+q,
        type: 'get'
    }).done(function(responseData) {
        console.log('Done: ', responseData);
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log('Failed');
    });
});
});
```

And the api code :

```
session_start()
$id=$_GET['id'];
$_SESSION[$id] = $_GET['q'];
echo 'success';
```

I used var_dump($_SESSION); to show all sessions

I enter api/save?id=8&q=4 , it print:

```
array(2) { [""]=> NULL [8]=> string(1) "4" }
```

But if I enter api/save , it print :

```
array(1) { [""]=> NULL }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used cookies instead of sessions and it works perfectely .

Thanks all.